# How can I send StormCrawler content to multiple Elasticsearch indices, based on host?

Tags: elasticsearch, stormcrawler

I currently have a successful StormCrawler instance crawling about 20 sites, and indexing the content to one Elasticsearch index. Is it possible, either in ES or via StormCrawler, to send each host's content to its own unique content index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity: why do you need to do that? Having one index per host seems rather wasteful. You can filter the results based on a field like host if you want to provide results for a particular host.

To answer your question, there is no direct way of doing it currently as the IndexerBolt it connected to one index only. You could declare one IndexerBolt per index you need and add a custom bolt to fan based on the value of the host metadata but this is not dynamic and rather heavy-handed. There could be a way of doing it using [pipelines in ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/pipeline.html), not sure.

Comment: Thank you, those suggestions were exactly what I was considering, and I also thought having so many IndexerBolts was too heavy-handed.

Comment: I was hoping to have them in individual indices to make the queries more efficient when the client filters their search by host. Also, many of the sites are simply various language versions of the same content, and their results will never appear with any other language, so it seemed very ineffiecient to have to search through those documents if there's no chance of them being called. I'll look more closely at ES pipelines, though - thank you!

Comment: Note that you could create an alias in ES with a filter query on your index (bases on hostname) so that it looks like a separate index. I don't think querying with a filter for the host would be inefficient. 
As for the language, again, you could filter based on the language, there even is a language detection module in StormCrawler

Comment: I think using aliases will be ideal - thanks. I hadn't seen the language module in StormCrawler either, that's fantastic. Thanks again!